# 'numpy.timedelta64' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

base=dsloc.time.values
time=np.array([base+np.timedelta64(step) for step in dsloc.step.values])
```

I was trying to use timeseries which is https://github.com/enyfeo/efas/blob/master/work/5_Timeseries.ipynb

I got the following error in the lines I specified; TypeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object is not iterable

Can you help me? thanks...

Edit;

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from random import sample
#%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()

stations = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/90531/Desktop/Lisflood/KONYA_LONG_LAT_4digit.xlsx')
#station = stations.sample(n=1) # We can randomly choose a station
station=stations[stations['stname'] == 300 ] # We have chosen a station for consistency
station
```

Comment: Can u get more info?i tried to reply but hacent ../static/EFAS_calib_stations_metadata.csv
in another way u can get us dsloc.values info and type

Comment: I use xlsx file as seen in the way I edited the post

Comment: Can u bring us this excel? i cant try on myself to see more info about error

Comment: sure, uploaded here we.tl/t-qqc5ksxrOn

Comment: need it too :

import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('../data/eue_15111800.nc')
clim = xr.open_dataset('../data/clim_151118.nc')

Comment: you can download clim_151118.nc from here; https://github.com/enyfeo/efas/blob/master/data/clim_151118.nc

Comment: did u change some more? its bring me no atributte LisfloodX, i think u change this parametter to another
dsloc = ds.sel(x=station.LisfloodX.values,y=station.LisfloodY.values,method='nearest')

Comment: yes i changed LisfloodX  as lat and LisfloodY as long

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ad4dba36d115ddfc3fd54740c736d14920210317121939/5e16df39c197dc5afdd5d1ab4c0cef4220210317121951/035975 you can use this nc file instead of eue_15111800.nc'

Comment: Fixed with your .nc, pls rate it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import sample
stations = pd.read_excel('KONYA_LONG_LAT_4digit.xlsx')
#station = stations.sample(n=1) # We can randomly choose a station
station=stations[stations['stname'] == 300 ] # We have chosen a station for consistency


import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('snow.nc')



# extract data for selected point in netcdf file by LISFLOOD coordinates
dsloc = ds.sel(x=station.lat.values,y=station.long.values,method='nearest')


import numpy as np

base=dsloc.time.values
time=np.array([base+np.timedelta64(step) for step in dsloc.step.values])
print(time)
```

output:

```
['2019-04-01T00:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-01T06:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-01T12:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-01T18:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-02T00:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-02T06:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-02T12:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-02T18:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-03T00:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-03T06:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-03T12:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-03T18:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-04T00:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-04T06:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-04T12:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-04T18:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-05T00:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-05T06:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-05T12:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-05T18:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-06T00:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-06T06:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-06T12:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-06T18:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-07T00:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-07T06:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-07T12:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-07T18:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-08T00:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-08T06:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-08T12:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-08T18:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-09T00:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-09T06:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-09T12:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-09T18:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-10T00:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-10T06:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-10T12:00:00.000000000' '2019-04-10T18:00:00.000000000'
 '2019-04-11T00:00:00.000000000']
```

Then, where its problem¿? On your nc havent dsloc.step.values, its vector, then u ve to iterate vector

How to fix? just look type of steps, try now:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import sample
stations = pd.read_excel('KONYA_LONG_LAT_4digit.xlsx')
#station = stations.sample(n=1) # We can randomly choose a station
station=stations[stations['stname'] == 300 ] # We have chosen a station for consistency


import xarray as xr
#ds = xr.open_dataset('snow.nc')
ds = xr.open_dataset('adaptor.efas_mars.external-1615983508.657324-23066-19-648c63b0-a6b0-4568-8970-d0f966ff16a2.nc')


# extract data for selected point in netcdf file by LISFLOOD coordinates
dsloc = ds.sel(x=station.lat.values,y=station.long.values,method='nearest')


import numpy as np

base=dsloc.time.values
steps = dsloc.step.values

if type(steps) == np.timedelta64:
    time=np.array([base+np.timedelta64(steps)])

else:
    time=np.array([base+np.timedelta64(step) for step in steps])

print(time)
```

Comment: Problem its on your .nc,

Comment: Thanks but the problem still not solved i get same error ; TypeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object is not iterable

Comment: That cause your nc its bad, im fixing code

Comment: then which nc file did you use?

Comment: xr.open_dataset('snow.nc')